# in JavaScript - select all elements with same class - except clicked one

Tags: javascript, css, accordion

**in JavaScript** - select all elements with same class - except clicked one

currently i am getting a result that works fine, but checking for a smart and simple solution

there are similar answers available using jquery `not`

```js
let color = document.querySelectorAll('.color');

let length = color.length;

// for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
//     color[i].onclick = () => {
//         color[i].classList.toggle('gold');
//     }
// }



// if gold exists on clicked element then remove it  
// if gold not exists on clicked element then remove from all element and add only on clicked element
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    color[i].onclick = () => {
        if (color[i].classList.contains('gold')) {
            color[i].classList.toggle('gold');  // remove / toggle
        } else {
            for (let x = 0; x < length; x++) {
                color[x].classList.remove('gold');
            }
            color[i].classList.toggle('gold');  // add / toggle
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.color {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.gold {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
</div>
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zzxgruo1/)

---

Comment: is there any best way to select all elements with same class except clicked one

Comment: yeah feel the same thing but not sure , waiting for better, smart solution

Comment: see vikas solution its working

Comment: Well did you pick a solution or come up with one of your own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
let color = document.querySelectorAll('.color')
let gold = 'gold'

color.forEach(
  (c) => c.onclick = (e) => {
      color.forEach(
        (c) => c.classList[e.target==c?'toggle':'remove'](gold)
      )
    }
)
```

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.color {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.gold {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could just click if i is x in the loop

```
color[i].onclick = () => {
  for (let x = 0; x < length; x++) {
    if (i===x) continue
    color[x].classList.remove('gold');
  }
  color[i].classList.toggle('gold');
}
```

or you could just use one click handler and check to see if what you clicked is what is selected

```js
let color = document.querySelector('.main');
color.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("main")) return
  var selected = color.querySelector(".gold")
  if (selected && selected!==e.target) selected.classList.remove('gold')
  e.target.classList.toggle('gold')
})
```

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.color {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.gold {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
</div>
```

Or no JavaScript at all

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.color {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}


input[name="a"] {
  display:none
}

input[name="a"]:checked + label {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <input type="radio" name="a" id="rb1"/><label class="color" for="rb1"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="a" id="rb2"/><label class="color" for="rb2"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="a" id="rb3"/><label class="color" for="rb3"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="a" id="rb4"/><label class="color" for="rb4"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="a" id="rb5"/><label class="color" for="rb5"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Added check to make sure it is not main.

Answer (score 1):

```
let color = document.querySelectorAll('.color');
let length = color.length;
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    color[i].onclick = () => {
        for (let x = 0; x < length; x++) {
            if (i===x) continue
            color[x].classList.remove('gold');
        }
        color[i].classList.toggle('gold');
    }
}
```

Comment: OP does not want a jQuery solution and that code is not even what the OP wants. OP wants $('.color').not(this).removeClass('gold');

Comment: friend, missing part is toggle - if click on same element again

Comment: @bhv Now see, added toggle

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

It's more efficient to attach the click event to the parent div than each of the children so I've gone about the solution a little differently to everyone else.

```js
document.querySelector(".main").onclick = (event) => {

  let element = event.target;

  if (element.classList.contains("color")) {

    document.querySelector(".main")

    let isGold = false;
    if (element.classList.contains("gold")) {
      isGold = true;
    }

    document.querySelectorAll(".gold").forEach((color) => color.classList.remove("gold"));
    
    if (!isGold) {
      element.classList.add("gold");
    }
  }
};
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.color {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.gold {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="color"></div>
  <div class="color"></div>
  <div class="color"></div>
  <div class="color"></div>
  <div class="color"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".color")).filter(function(element) {
        return element !== event.target;
    })); // This should print all elements with the class "color" except the clicked one
});
```

Edit: After taking another look at the question, is this more of what you are trying to do?

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.target.classList.add("gold");
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("color")).forEach(function(element) {
        if (element !== event.target)
            element.classList.remove("gold"); // Don't need to exist to remove apparently
    });
});
```

Final edit (hopefully): Now it works exactly like your demo.

```
document.querySelector(".main").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.target.classList.toggle("gold");
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".color")).forEach((element) => {
        if (element !== event.target)
            element.classList.remove("gold");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do it..

```js
let colors = document.querySelectorAll('.color');

let length = colors.length;

colors.forEach(function (color, index) {
  color.onclick = () => {
    colors.forEach(function(c, i) {
      c.classList[index === i ? "toggle" : "remove"]('gold');
    });
  };
});
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.color {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.gold {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="color"></div>
  <div class="color"></div>
  <div class="color"></div>
  <div class="color"></div>
  <div class="color"></div>
</div>
```

With radio buttons:

```js
let colors = document.querySelectorAll('[name="color"]');
var checked = -1;
colors.forEach(function(color, index) {
  color.onclick = () => {
    if (checked === index) {
      color.checked = false;
      checked = -1;
    } else
      checked = index;
  };
});
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

label {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: white;
}

.gold {
  background-color: gold;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input:checked+label {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="color">
  <label for="radio1"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="color">
  <label for="radio2"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="color">
  <label for="radio3"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="color">
  <label for="radio4"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio5" name="color">
  <label for="radio5"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fetched multiple list-item with the same class name. Need to show/hide list details by clicked list item. Below code may help someone -

```
function getDetailMsg(clicked){
    var len = document.getElementsByClassName("msg-accordion").length;
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("msg-accordion");

    acc[clicked].classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = acc[clicked].nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
        for (let x = 0; x < len; x++) {
            var oldpanel = acc[x].nextElementSibling;
            if (clicked!=x) { 
                oldpanel.style.maxHeight = null;
                acc[x].classList.remove('active'); 
            }
        }
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
}
```

```html
<div class="list-group">
<div class="list-group-item justify-content-between msg-accordion" onclick="getDetailMsg('0');">Subject 1</div>
<div class="panel bg-warning text-white">Body 1</div>
<div class="list-group-item justify-content-between msg-accordion" onclick="getDetailMsg('1');">Subject 2</div>
<div class="panel bg-warning text-white">Body 2</div></div>
```